# bias and variance decomposition derivation trick

Tags: mathematical-statistics, bias-variance-tradeoff

I am following the derivation from [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4780/2018fa/lectures/lecturenote12.html). My question is about the first trick, where the author claims that:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
E_{\mathbf{x}, y, D}\left[\left[h_{D}(\mathbf{x})-y\right]^{2}\right] &=E_{\mathbf{x}, y, D}\left[\left[\left(h_{D}(\mathbf{x})-\bar{h}(\mathbf{x})\right)+(\bar{h}(\mathbf{x})-y)\right]^{2}\right] \\
&=E_{\mathbf{x}, D}\left[\left(h_{D}(\mathbf{x})-\bar{h}(\mathbf{x})\right)^{2}\right]+2 E_{\mathbf{x}, y, D}\left[\left(h_{D}(\mathbf{x})-\bar{h}(\mathbf{x})\right)(\bar{h}(\mathbf{x})-y)\right]+E_{\mathbf{x}, y}\left[(\bar{h}(\mathbf{x})-y)^{2}\right]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

This was just the expansion in the form $(a+b)^2 = a^2+2ab+b^2$, where:

\begin{equation}
a = E_{\mathbf{x}, D}[(h_{D}(\mathbf{x})-\bar{h}(\mathbf{x}))] \\
b = E_{\mathbf{x}, y}[(\bar{h}(\mathbf{x})-y)]
\end{equation}

Then, the author cancels out the middle term ($2ab$) by:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
E_{\mathbf{x}, y, D}\left[\left(h_{D}(\mathbf{x})-\bar{h}(\mathbf{x})\right)(\bar{h}(\mathbf{x})-y)\right] &=E_{\mathbf{x}, y}\left[E_{D}\left[h_{D}(\mathbf{x})-\bar{h}(\mathbf{x})\right](\bar{h}(\mathbf{x})-y)\right] \\
&=E_{\mathbf{x}, y}\left[\left(E_{D}\left[h_{D}(\mathbf{x})\right]-\bar{h}(\mathbf{x})\right)(\bar{h}(\mathbf{x})-y)\right] \\
&=E_{\mathbf{x}, y}[(\bar{h}(\mathbf{x})-\bar{h}(\mathbf{x}))(\bar{h}(\mathbf{x})-y)] \\
&=E_{\mathbf{x}, y}[0] \\
&=0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

In that way, we are saying that $a = 0$, and therefore canceling the whole $2ab$ term. Nonetheless, if this is the case why the first term $a$ or $E_{\mathbf{x}, D}[(h_{D}(\mathbf{x})-\bar{h}(\mathbf{x}))]$ continues in the final formula?

\begin{equation}
E_{\mathbf{x}, y, D}\left[\left(h_{D}(\mathbf{x})-y\right)^{2}\right]=\underbrace{E_{\mathbf{x}, D}\left[\left(h_{D}(\mathbf{x})-\bar{h}(\mathbf{x})\right)^{2}\right]}_{\text {Variance }}+E_{\mathbf{x}, y}\left[(\bar{h}(\mathbf{x})-y)^{2}\right]
\end{equation}

I know this is wrong, but I can not find why. What am I missing here?

Comment: What do you mean by "$a$"??  The algebra is clear and it comes down to asserting $\bar h(x)-\bar h(x)=0,$ something that should not require any discussion.

Comment: I mean that $ 
a = E_{\mathbf{x}, y, D}\left[\left(h_{D}(\mathbf{x})-\bar{h}(\mathbf{x})\right)(\bar{h}(\mathbf{x})-y)\right]$. Could you explain what am I doing wrong? In that way I will be able to see why this doesn't require any discussion.

Comment: So far, you have quoted a derivation.  I cannot see anything that you are doing at all.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question to be more precise. My point is that in the expansion $a^2 + 2ab + b^2$ we cancel $2ab$ by saying that $a=0$ and if this is the case, why we kept the first $a$ in the formula at the end? It should not be cancelled out too?

Comment: Your expansion is not a valid characterization of the algebra.  You need to pay attention to the subscripts of the expectation operators.  Notice that they *differ* among the different terms.

Comment: yes, they all differ, but if we derive the $a$ term we will be able to cancel it out. But, as pointed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/statistics/comments/tjqp5f/comment/i1m3sjs/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), my mistake was assuming that since $E[a] = 0$ implies that $E[a^2] = 0$, which is incorrect.